# Python date string conversion fail

Tags: python

I am trying to convert the following string '1.12.22 14:16UTC+01:00' in Pandas to December 1st 2022

```
my_date = '1.12.22 14:16UTC+01:00'
new_date = pd.to_datetime(my_date)
```

Timestamp('2022-01-12 14:16:00-0100', tz='pytz.FixedOffset(-60)')

It inverts month with day only in specific cases. I am trying to use format="%d.%m.%Y %H:%M%z" but it says that the string is not matching the format.

`time data '1.12.22 14:16UTC+01:00' does not match format '%d.%m.%Y %H:%M%z' (match)`

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Check the docs https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior  `%z` doesn't work as you expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> pd.to_datetime('01.12.22 14:16UTC', format='%d.%m.%y %H:%M%Z')
Timestamp('2022-12-01 14:16:00+0000', tz='UTC')
```

I am not sure if this is what you are looking for, but your placeholders are wrong, check [this page](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Period.strftime.html) to know what they stand for.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried adding a zero?

`my_date = '01.12.22 14:16UTC+01:00'`